# passing a string argument to name a job in SLURM

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, slurm

I want to pass a parameter to as bash script in a cluster in order to name the job. I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J "$1" #<--- to name the job with the first parameter
#SBATCH --partition=shortq
#SBATCH -o %x-%j.out
#SBATCH -e %x-%j.err


echo "this is a test job named" $1
Gate main.mac
```

When I launch the job with

```
sbatch my_script.sh  test_sript
```

I'm getting a file named $1-23472.out . It appears that "$1" didn't be interpreted. How can I have a file named "test_script-23472.out" ?

Also, is the line Gate main.mac mandatory? Can anyone explains me why we should put it ?

Many thanks

Comment: This question may be more related to the usage of Slurm Workfload Manager than to the shell. Would it make sense to tag your question with `slurm`? Your code runs fine when it is run as a regular shell script on Linux.

Comment: Ok I will add a targ with SLURM. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do it exactly as you want to, but here's a solution that comes pretty close:

Batch script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=shortq
#SBATCH -o %x-%j.out
#SBATCH -e %x-%j.err


echo "this is a test job named" $SLURM_JOB_NAME
(rest of your script here)
```

Submit with:

```
$ sbatch -J jobname my_script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Slurm will not interpret the Bash variable in the comments. Bash either since it is in a comment.

One solution is a construct like this for submission:

```
ARG="<something>" sbatch -J "$ARG" my_script.sh  test_sript "$ARG"
```

As for the `Gate main.mac` line, it is used to start the [Gate](https://github.com/OpenGATE/Gate) program with `main.mac` as argument.

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work. When I delete the line ' #SBATCH -J "$1" 'from the script, I'm getting two files with names : -23913.err and -23913.out

Comment: I remark also when I launch the script with : sbatch -J "test_sript" my_script.sh     this works fine. It generates two files caller test_sript.out and test_sript.err

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've been formatting slurm scripts to parse bash variables as job names.

```
#!/bin/bash
MYVAR=$1

sbatch --export=ALL -J ${MYVAR} --wrap="run something"
```